# 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type Function

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm doing a  Flash project for my course. I'm very new and can't seem to get anything to work properly (I gave up on document classes).

My problem is I have a timer, and with each tick it adds to some integers based on a given value. But that isn't the problem, my code will not allow the timer to work, it's in a class called "CounterCode" and when I was getting the timer to go to "CounterA" function it said "Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor" So now I'm sending it to the CounterCode constructor function and It's giving the above error.

I'll give a snippet of the code but ask for more if needed, I've not been doing Flash long so please excuse any cringe worthy code.

```
public static var turnTimer:Timer = new Timer(500, 100);
    turnTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, CounterCode);


    public function CounterCode(Event:TimerEvent):void {
```

This seems to be where the problem is but I can't seem to figure out what it is, I've searched a lot but it's not really seeming relevant to my problem.

--EDIT WITH FULL CODE--

```
package  {

import Fighter;
import Rogue;
import Mage;
import Healer;
import MonsterOne;
import MonsterTwo;
import MonsterThree;
import MonsterFour;
import turn;

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

public class CounterCode extends MovieClip {

    public static var fighterCount:int = 0;
    public static var rogueCount:int = 0;
    public static var mageCount:int = 0;
    public static var healerCount:int = 0;
    public static var fullCount:Number = 100;
    public static var monsCount:Number = 0;
    public static var whoTurn = String(whoTurn);
    public static var turnFighter:MovieClip = turnFighter as MovieClip;
    public static var turnRogue:MovieClip = turnRogue as MovieClip;
    public static var turnMage:MovieClip = turnMage as MovieClip;
    public static var turnHealer:MovieClip = turnHealer as MovieClip;

    public static var tGo = new tGo();

    public static var turnTimer:Timer = new Timer(500, 100);
    turnTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, CounterCode);


    public function CounterCode(Event:TimerEvent):void {
        var randChoice;
        trace(fighterCount);
        fighterCount += Fighter.aSpeed;
        rogueCount += Rogue.aSpeed;
        mageCount += Mage.aSpeed;
        healerCount += Healer.aSpeed;

        if(monsCount >= 100) {
            whoTurn = "monT";
            turnTimer.stop();
            randChoice();
        }

        if(fighterCount >= 100) {
            whoTurn = "fighterT";
            turnTimer.stop();
            trace("stop");
            tGo();
        }

         if(rogueCount >= 100) {
            whoTurn = "rogueT";
            turnTimer.stop();
            tGo();
        }

        if(mageCount >= 100) {
            whoTurn = "mageT";
            turnTimer.stop();
            tGo();
        }

        if(healerCount >= 100) {
            whoTurn = "healerT";
            turnTimer.stop();
            tGo();
        }
    }       
}
```

}

Thank you

Comment: you can't use a constructor as a listener.

Comment: I tested your code. It works fine. I think the problem is not in these lines . check out the number of line of the error.

Comment: That code does not work fine at all, you misunderstand the setup. CounterCode is not a method but the constructor of the class CounterCode. Now try again with that setup and see if that works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! BotMaster, when I use another function instead of the constructor it gives the 1007 error. Any idea's? Same code just  goes to say "CounterA" instead of "CounterCode" from the timer. Thanks again!